# Export CSV with Javascript and display progress bar

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv, progress-bar

Is there a way to display a progress bar while a CSV file is being generated and served up via ajax?  The CSV file takes a while to generate due to the database, and need a loader on the screen and hide it when it is done.  I would like this to be ajax or stay on the same page if necessary.  Right now I am doing this below, but I can't tell when the file is done downloading to stop the progress.

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
                iframe.src = (value.url);
                iframe.style.display = "none";
                document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation correctly you are generating a file on the server side when you receive a request, saving it to disk and then serving it up from there.  If that is what you are doing you have two options:

1. Update some shared state (memcached, redis, mongodb, a sqlite database or a file) from your generating code when you start generating the file with the total number of rows you have to generate and the number of rows you have currently generated.  Make additional ajax requests back to an endpoint that will give you the current values from that shared state.
2. Stream the generated CSV file straight back to the client - unless the fetching of the data takes the majority of the time this will result in a faster appearance of the download dialog and an *apparent* speed up.

Comment: I'm not saving it to a disk, just serving it up.  I am trying to stop the progress bar once it is done computing.  Your solution of storing it in a temp file might be my only option because then I could stop the progress and download the file with the second request.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1678390.aspx/1?how+to+implement+file+download+progressbar+in+MVC+

Comment: @MikeFlynn - yep, updating a static variable as you are streaming the file down and hitting another web service to get the value in the static variable counts as an instance of option #1.